# SQL - Partial Sum of results for two different columns

Tags: sql, db2

Okay, so, let's pretend I have a table like this:

```
Name Rank Score
Adam 1    10
Adam 2    20
Adam 3    14
Jane 2    11
Jane 3    14
Jane 4    45
Rick 1    49
Rick 3    24
Rick 5    12
```

I need to produce a set of results in a single table that SUMs ranks 1 and 2 in one column, and ranks 3+ in the second column. I can do this as two separate SQL statements, like so:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Score) AS Score1
FROM Table
WHERE Rank < 3
GROUP BY Name
```

and

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Score) AS Score2
FROM Table
WHERE Rank > 2
GROUP BY Name
```

But I can't think of any way to produce a single SQL statement that results in a single table, that might look like this:

```
Name Score1 Score2
Adam 30     14
Jane 11     59
Rick 49     36
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This assumes `Ranks` are integers:

```
SELECT Name, 
    sum(case when Rank in (1, 2) then Score else null end) as Score1,
    sum(case when Rank < 1 or Rank > 2 then Score else null end) as Score2
FROM Table 
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: +1, but why `Rank < 1 or Rank > 2`? The OP was explicit enough: `ranks 3+ in the second column`, so it should be just `Rank > 2`.

Comment: @Andriy - I was considering that there could be ranks less than 1 (perhaps at some future date), and that the OP wanted to count all ranks either in or not in the set (1, 2). That could be an incorrect assumption. I'll lve it to the OP to update if they wish...